# Using external static library in LPCXpresso

Tags: static, libjpeg, lpc

I am using the LPCXpresso IDE to program my microcontroller to use the libjpeg library for a particular application. However, I cannot seem to get the LPCXpresso IDE to recognize libjpeg. The way I see it, there are two options:

1) Take the jpeglib.a file, include it as an external library, and then attempt to import jpeglib.h. I have tried this, at the IDE still does not recognize jpeglib.h.

2) Create a new static library from the libjpeg source code. Is this my only option? It seems a bit excessive.

Any tips regarding adding/linking external libraries in LPCXpresso would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily add a library to Eclipse/LPCXpresso by creating a new project (not a C project or a LPCXpresso project but a 'normal' project) by clicking File->New->Project. Name is as you wish, let's say 'JPEG'. Add your library file to it under the folder 'lib' (you have to create the folder first). Call the library file 'libJPEG.a'. Also include the header file under the folder 'inc'. It is not mandatory to create these folders by the way, but it makes it all more organised.

The edit the properties of the project that's needs to include the header and library. Right click the project and choose properties. Go to C/C++ Build->Settings->MCU C compiler->Includes and add the include path of the inc folder of the library project. The go to C/C++ Build->Settings->MCU Linker->Libraries and add the library file WITHOUT the lib in front of the file name, hence just JPEG. Also add the library search path below (point to the lib folder).

That's all!